# Browser overrides CSS implementation on Live Server

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, browser-cache

I´m new to webdevelopment, and I'm coding a simple app, using VSCode and the Live Server extension.

My files are linked correctly, but some of the CSS changes are not implemented on the website (i.e. background-color, font-family)

[PrintScreen of the code and page shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P0m3.png)

As I looked in the DevTools I can see that the changes are being overrided and not being implemented.

[Background color override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W56G7.png)

[Font-family overide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9BUq.png)

What can I do to solve this problem?

I've tried to use diferent extensions (using Edge within the VSCode), clearing the cache and even disabling it, hoping that this would force the CSS changes to work, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link your CSS file at the end of the head tag. Please re-arrange your code as below.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```